# Get data from another form on different pages WPforms plugin

Tags: wordpress, hook-wordpress

I created a form where I fill in the data with a dropdown taking this data from a JSON file and when I click on the send button it takes me to another form where the fields of the first one are already filled in and other fields are blank. The forms are on different pages. I managed to retrieve the ID of the first form in the fields of the second. However, I can’t show the value in the second form, it always returns the field ID. I’m using the following nomenclature in the first form to send the data:

`https://my_url/?wpf553_18={field_value_id="ID"}`

However, as I said in the second, it only returns the id of the field and not the value. I registered the following script in functions:

```
add_filter( 'wpforms_fields_show_options_setting', '__return_true' );
```

Can you help me to know what is happening to return the value of the field?

I've already managed to get the field with the code: `{field_value_id="ID"}`, but it always returns the form's ID and not its value